# How to get pid of a remote process submitted in ksh via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, ksh

I am writing a KSH script on a Linux server.  It needs to submit a batch job on a remote Linux server via ssh.  The difficult part is to get the pid of the remote process back to parent process.

I hope experts here can help.

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: What have you done so far? What approach you are thinking about?

Comment: Try this `pid=$(ssh remoteuser@remotehost 'jobsubmissionscript > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!')`.

Comment: looks like this isn't what the OP is asking for. Very careless

Comment: @alvits:  Not the OP here but, that worked for me: `pid=$(ssh $server 'nohup sar -A -o /opt/uad/$(hostname -s).sardata.bin 3  > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!')`  where $pid then contained the pid of the persistent sar command on $server which I was able to later kill with `ssh $server "kill $pid"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
pid=$(ssh localhost "pgrep -u user ipython")
```

This will ssh into the host and get the process (ipython) id running as user

Then you can do

```
echo $pid
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That's just careless. The OP is interested in the job most recently submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   Yes, something likes this.    However, when I run similar line from a shell script.  The echo output shows up in stdout as well.  Hopefully, I can find a way to make it only sends to the local shell variable pid.    John